# Integrating Google Analytics in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics into my app but it's not sending me a report or anything. I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/) guide from Google, I pasted the .jar file in my libs folder, I set the build path, I did everything the guide told me to, but I get nothing. I get no errors but when I run it on the emulator I do not get any reports and the log-cat is not showing anything.  Am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks!!

MY MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS:

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
public class myTrackedActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The rest of your onStart() code.
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.


      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
       // The rest of your onStop() code.
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
      }
    }

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.primarycode.punnyjokes.MESSAGE";
//public static int iteration = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

}
```

ANALYTICS.XML IN MY VALUES

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<resources>
  <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-43160348-1</string>

  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
  <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten initing your EasyTracker. Do it in your onCreate of your Application class of your project.

```
onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
}
```